# Got error below while executing Eclipse (Selenium)

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

Using Firefox version (53.0.3 (32-bit)) / Selenium (selenium-java-3.4.0).

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable is a directory: F:\Selenium\GecKo
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:518)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:330)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
    at Login.Login.main(Login.java:13)
```

Comment: You need to specify path till the geckodriver.exe

Comment: Including the .exe part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while setting the system property, we need to give the complete path of the driver executable.

```
System.setproperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","F:\\Selenium\\GecKo.exe");
```

Comment: **Problem is solve But after Execute Script Getting New Error.**  1498155711634 geckodriver INFO Listening on 127.0.0.1:35808
1498155713157 geckodriver::marionette INFO Starting browser C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
1498155724471 Marionette INFO Listening on port 1594
Jun 22, 2017 11:52:05 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

Comment: This is not an err. This is the default behaviour